# to fix the footer in the page of jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have an issue with the footer of a mobile site built using jQuery Mobile.

When I cut the footer's `data-position="fix"` the footer is fixed to a position, but the page contents are small amount, so the footer is not fixed with the desktop footer position.

How can I fix the issue of the jQuery mobile site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div data-role="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-role="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom: 0; left:0;">
</div>
```